# From Wald test statistic to P-value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, p-value, wald-test

Lets say I have a dataset with a binary target variablem, smoker / non smoker, and a continuous variable of miles running per week.

So for each catigory (`smoker` or `non smoker`), I calculated the mean (of miles ran per week..), variance, sample size and the standrad error

Now for the hypothesis testing, the following are the null hypothesis, the alternative, test statistic and rejection region. I decided on a 0.05 level of confidence.

[image]

And now I have the test statistic |W|. How do I find the p-value? the samples are not normaly distributed.

Comment: The Wald test is the asymptotic test. You would need to calculate the Z value, not the T value for the two sample test. Then, compare to the ch square distn with 1 df.

Comment: What does the lack of normality have to do with anything?